# C++ code coverage tool

Tags: java, c++, c, c++builder

I am looking for c++ code coverage tool which fares well in mutli server setup and on both windows and linux without licensing issues(if non free).

I have done some research and found 2 free tools: Covtool and gcov. Any disadvantages on these or any other suggestions?

Comment: [GCov/LCov article](http://bobah.net/d4d/tools/code-coverage-with-gcov). Last time I checked the GCC instrumentation rig was not thread safe, so worth googling specifically if you plan to run it on anything beyond unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't remember all the details of my research for code coverage tools, I seem to remember the following about gcov and covtool:

- They require custom modifications to your build system
- They need custom compiler flags and/or link steps
- They both provide minimal output and formatting

We needed support for Windows/Linux and gcc/MSVC and settled on [BullseyeCoverage](http://www.bullseye.com/) which is commercial and non-free. We estimated that it would cost us more, in money, to change our build system to use the free products than it would to pay for a BullseyeCoverage license.   Their support was great and responsive and I was very pleased with the quality of the tool.

Some benefits:

- Great query support both in command line and GUI form
- Required **no** changes to our build system
- Had minimal impact on both compile time and run time
- Provides tools to integrate with build bots such as CruiseControl and Hudson
- Nice GUI for visualization and navigation of coverage results

Answer (score 0):

AQTime is popular for Delphi/C++Builder users, but like the other recommendation, it is not free.

Comment: Thankyou. Any free C++ code coverage tool reccomendations?

Answer (score 0):

The OovAide program is a free open source tool that will instrument source files
and generate code coverage statistics as well as show which lines were never
run.  It is thread safe and efficient.

It is fairly transparent meaning that the code that it produces is all visibile
and can be modified for your project if there are special needs required.

The basic idea of the source code modifications is that it inserts a macro
at every grouping of statements in the AST that CLang is processing.
This is typically after the conditionals or at braces.  The macro can be
modified, but the default is that it increments a value at an offset in
an array.  I have also modified it to write to a file in some cases,
and this allows a program trace of execution.

One problem may be that its build system is limited, and must be able to be
built using CLang. It may not work on certain types of projects.  But since
it just modifies source code by inserting the macro, it is possible to
use it to modify the source code, then use the existing build system to
build the modified source code.

There is a document describing how it works here. http://oovaide.sourceforge.net/articles/TestCoverage.html

Answer (score 0):

use Gcov tool along with LCOV tool. LCOV tool is a graphical front-end for gcov.